# Excel sheet with column with number stored as text as well as integers- pandas issue

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My input data is from three excel sheets and few columns (integer data) data are stored as text. What is the best practice to do when reading the excel sheet as dataframe. I am having an issue when I try to pd.concat all three dataframes. I am getting more number rows than expected during `pd.concat` process.

I tried conversion using astype() to int as well as removing white spaces with `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`

Let me know the best practice to resolve this.

Comment: Can you provide two sample data sets that lead to that problem?

Comment: This is related to my earlier post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603076/compare-column-values-in-two-or-three-dataframe-and-merge/58603366#58603366    The first column ```Name``` is an integer and instead of getting 4 lines as expected, I get more number of lines. I get two lines per Id instead of 1. I have three excel sheets respective dataframe

Comment: Do you have the same columns for each excel sheet or is it different columns?

Comment: Differet columns. But I have harmonized or renamed the columns such that they are the same before I group by. One of the column type is "object"  in df2 and not the int type as others. This column has few rows with `#` I am trying to remove those rows to see if I can convert this column into int type and hence I get the desired output. Thanks.

Comment: So why are we still seeing the three different header names in your answer below (sales_Amount1, sales_Amount2, target_Amount)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes the last column in each df are different and that's why. I managed to figure out the issue. As I mentioned earlier, I dropped the orws with `3` from one column and convert that column into int type. This resolved the  issue. Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had to post here for the issue that I am facing. I get two lines instead of one line for each comparison. When I looked at the results excel sheet, some ids are stored as text and some are not. Hence they both are treated as two lines during comparisons amidst 3 dataframes using `pd.concat` Thanks.

```
    Id    Year    Item  sales_Amount1  sales_Amount2  target_Amount
    1234  1.2019   Badam             0              70            100
    1234  1.2019   Badam             12              0            0
    1234  1.2019  carrot             0               0            200
    1234  1.2019  carrot             18              0            0
```

Comment: df.info gives as int64 type for all three dataframes.